# Why do multiple iterations of a block of code increase average running time so much?

Tags: java

For example, I'm running a simple nested loop that finds duplicate elements in two arrays.  With a list size of 2000, it takes somewhere around 25 milliseconds on average (a guess) if I run the program several times in a row.  However, running the program once within a for loop, the more times I loop it, the faster the average runtime for one iteration is.  e.g. 10 times is 5 milliseconds each iteration, 10000 times is 2 milliseconds.

I have to measure the running time for a few different types of list intersection (e.g. nested loops, binary search etc.) at various list sizes, so I'm not sure which is more accurate.  It becomes more of a problem for the longer ones because it takes too long to run it so many times.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length-1; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j]) {
                inter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

How I generate the lists used:

```
public studentList(int size, String course) {
int IDrange=2*size;
studentID=new int[size];
boolean[] usedID=new boolean[IDrange];
for (int i=0;i<IDrange;i++) usedID[i]=false;
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    int t;
    do {
    t=(int)(Math.random()*IDrange);
    } while (usedID[t]);
    usedID[t]=true;
    studentID[i]=t;
}
courseName=course;
numberOfStudents=size;
}
```

Comment: The most probable without seeing the code is that you have an algoritm that isn't optimal. But none can be strictly linear for searching for duplicates.

Comment: Without code, I'd vote to close.

Comment: Profile before - guess later

Comment: I'm confused. You say 'the more times I loop it, the greater the average runtime', then say '10 times is 5ms... 10,000 times is 2ms'... which is the opposite of the previous statement

Comment: What Dancrumb said: Based on your description, it sounds like the average time per iteration *decreases* as the number of iterations increase.

Comment: My mistake, was thinking faster, typed greater.

Comment: Without seeing all the code you're running (i.e. how you're running the loop you've posted), I'd guess it's Hotspot VM adaptive optimization kicking in as the loop is run more, that causes average iteration time to drop.  Or, it could be that other non-loop operations get amortized over the increased iteration count. Again, just speculation.

Comment: @Peter It's pretty basic, in main method I created two random lists and called the method from the code posted. That call is in another for loop and at the start/end of the for loop are variables to store the start/end time (System.nanoTime()).  The only thing I can think it might be that's specific to my code is how the list was generated (added to main post).

Answer (score 2):

The java virtual machine optimizes a program while it is running. When the same section of code gets executed frequently, the program flow will be optimized around this code path so that it is executed as quickly as possible.

When you want to benchmark algorithms, the usual practice is to execute them multiple times and discard the time measurements of the first few iterations.

But note that there are also other factors which can meddle with your time measurements, like the unpredictable garbage collector which can start to work whenever it wants and slows down the rest of the JVM.

Comment: He claims to get faster average runs when he only runs one. Most likely memory usage is slowing it down. If he did a gc call every call it could help.

Comment: @Legend he corrected himself. The question now reads "the more times I loop it, the faster the average runtime for one iteration"

Comment: @Legend but thanks for mentioning garbage collection, that reminded me of another pitfall when benchmarking java programs